# python print statement printing a newline despite a comma

Tags: python

'2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) \n[GCC 4.4.3]'

I have this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

f = open('filetest', 'w')
f.write("This is a line")

f.close()

f = open('filetest', 'r')


for i in f.readlines():
    print i,
```

This prints the o/p like this:

```
$ ./filetest.py 
This is a line
abc@abc-ubuntu:~/pythonpractice$
```

I am wondering why does the prompt go to the newline after "This is a line" is printed?
Because `cat filestest` gives this:

```
$ cat filetest
This is a lineabc@abc-ubuntu:~/pythonpractice$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR you can also use:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

with open('filetest', 'w') as f1:
    f1.write("This is a line")

with open('filetest', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2.readlines():
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Try to always use "with" when you work with files, this is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

This is standard behavior, afaik.  You can use sys.output.write instead, or you can
set sys.output.softspace=False to prevent the newline.

See this article for more details: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/419182/

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function

for line in f:
    print(line, end="")
```